# Laravel where clause of current and related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to compare `current table column` to `related table column`

example: A.quantity < B.criticalQuantity

similarly like this `AModel::where('quantity', "<", "b.criticalQuantity")->get()`

the relations is

```
B HasMany A
A BelongsTo B
```

Comment: If both table has a relation, then you may try whereHas method

Comment: @sta where has is getting if B column condition. not comparing along with a column, in raw sql it esimilar with ```where exists (select b where condition)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [whereColumn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses)

it is specialist in comparing columns not a column with value.

anyway you can't directly compare two columns from two table, you have to join them first by anyway of join types

something like:

```
$values = ModelA::join('model_b_table_name', 'model_b_table_name.id', 'model_a_table_name.model_b_id')
            ->whereColumn('model_b_table_name.column.quantity', 'model_b_table_name.quantity')
            ->get();
```

you must be specific in joining the table, you should join by the columns that consist the relation between the two tables.

Comment: if you share your models and the relation between them, the answer would be clearer

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question with the relation info, could you update the answer too,  thankyou

Comment: i have update it, could you tell me what exactly the query should get? for example: all record from table a where the quantity is greater or equal to quantity in related table b?

Comment: this already answer the general question of it. the key word is ```join``` and ```where column``` , but for more explanation of the case, the ```B Tabel``` is the master data and having the column criticalQuantity. actualy A is pivot table another 1 of ```location tabel```. so location ```many-to-many``` B

Comment: you can also use whereColumn inside the statement that use the relation like:
whereHas, with ....

Comment: just curious, is it I have to use ```join```? because I must provide the table name manually again, not by chaining function ```Builder\Eloquent```,  ```join``` is already ```Builder\Query``` instance, ,

Answer (score 1):

```
->whereRaw('table_1.name = table_2.name')
```

Comment: it gives error of ```missing FROM-clause entry for table "table_2"``` like not yet aliased